# Autocreation appropriate DATETIME type fields using JDBC Sink Connector on SQL Server

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, debezium

I use Debezium 1.2

I have MSSQL databases and want to publish data from one table to many other tables in other DBs (usual scenario for Debezium)

So i setup MSSQL Source Connector and JDBC Sink Connector.
Everything is fine except one thing. `DATETIME` columns are created as `INT64` in consumer`s Databases.

I fixed it with such code in JDBC sink config:

```
        "transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS",
        "transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "Timestamp",
        "transforms.TimestampConverter.field ": "date3",
```

Actually it works, but I have to write *ALL* columns of source tables (should I?). An in case multiple topics it will be not possible.

So here is the question:
How can I configure sink/source to allow crete `DATETIME` columns automatically without iterating all known columns?

Comment: Could you create a VIEW on the database that does the conversion instead?

Comment: oh! brilliant actually idea! but still i will need review eaach table for DateTime columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `time.precision.mode=connect` - see https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-temporal-values

Comment: But then there is an issue with infinity datetime columns if your database is Postgres